# PHP form post, automatically mapping to an object (model binding)

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I do a lot of ASP.NET MVC 2 development, but I'm tackling a small project at work and it needs to be done in PHP.

Is there anything built-in to PHP to do model binding, mapping form post fields to a class?  Some of my PHP code currently looks like this:

```
class EntryForm
{
    public $FirstName = "";
    public $LastName = "";
}

    $EntryForm = new EntryForm();

if ($_POST && $_POST["Submit"] == "Submit")
{
    $EntryForm->FirstName = trim($_POST["FirstName"]);
    $EntryForm->LastName = trim($_POST["LastName"]);
}
```

Is there anything built-in to a typical PHP install that would do such mapping like you'd find in ASP.NET MVC, or does it require an additional framework?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not native but a better solution that permits you using your own classes or a standard class ...

```
function populateWithPost ($obj = NULL)
{
  if(is_object($obj)) {

  } else {
      $obj = new StdClass ();
  }

  foreach ($_POST as $var => $value) {
      $obj->$var = trim($value); //here you can add a filter, like htmlentities ...
  }

  return $obj;
}
```

And then you can use it like:

```
class EntryForm
{
    public $FirstName = "";
    public $LastName = "";
}

$entry = populateWithPost(new EntryForm());
```

or

```
 $obj = populateWithPost();
```

Comment: Thanks!  One small change and it worked perfectly.

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
   $obj->$key = trim($value); 
}

Comment: Old thread but  `$obj->$var = trim($value);` could also be replaced by `$model->$var = $this->input->post($var);`

Comment: I used a second argument to function to pass  the `$data`. Then, `$_POST`, `$_GET` and even a database `$row` can be passed as argument and mapped to an object.

Answer (score 1):

Built in to PHP? No.

The framework answer you hint at is where you'll need to go for this one (after all, ASP.NET is a framework too)

Comment: old post, I know, but just clarifying.... ASP .NET is not a Framework.  .NET is a Framework.

Comment: @devlincarnate ASP.NET __is indeed a framework__. Quoting from ASP.NET's official website, "ASP.NET is an open source web framework for building modern web apps..." [ASP.NET Website] (https://www.asp.net/)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an ORM (Object Relationship Mapping) layer.  PHP has a couple, one of which is [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).  That said, mahomedalidp's answer is very handy for getting things done in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built into PHP for this.  But easy to implement in your EntryForm class.  You could add `public function populate($post)` to `EntryForm` and pass it the $_POST variable.  It would loop through and if the class attribute exists, set it.  In fact, you could build an abstract class that implements `populate()` and extend it with your EntryForm, or any other form you want.  You'll want to sanitize the input as well, of course.